# Can anyone share some tricks to rewriting triple integral order

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So, I was wondering if anyone can share some tricks or a systematic way on re-writing a triple integral.

Here's the exercise I'm doing.

$\int _{-1} ^1 \int _0 ^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int _0 ^ {y/2} f(x, y ,z)dz\ dy\ dx$

I'm trying to rewrite this to $dy\ dx\ dz$.

I have drawn the "picture" out and realize its sort of a half-cylinder being sliced by the plane $z = (y/2)$ . (Correct me if I'm wrong with the description)

So is there a systematic way to change the order of integration ? I am able to do (quite efficiently) for a double integrals, but I am extremely confused when it comes to triple integral.

Any tips and insights will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can write all the limits as inequalities and then deduce the new bounds from them in order from outside to inside.

In your case, you have

$$
-1\lt x\lt1\;,\\
0\lt y\lt\sqrt{1-x^2}\;,\\
0\lt z\lt \frac y2\;.
$$

For the new integration order, $z$ is on the outside, so you need the overall bounds for $z$. From the given inequalities, the range of $x$ is $[-1,1]$, thus the range of $y$ is $[0,1]$ and thus the range of $z$ is $[0,\frac12]$.

$x$ is next, so we need to solve the second inequality for $x$, yielding $|x|\lt\sqrt{1-y^2}$. Together with $y\gt 2z$ from the third inequality, this yields $|x|\lt\sqrt{1-4z^2}$, so the range of $x$ is $[-\sqrt{1-4z^2},\sqrt{1-4z^2}]$. Finally, $y$ is bounded both by $y\gt2z$ and by $y\lt\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so its range is $[2z,\sqrt{1-x^2}]$. Thus the integral is

$$
\int_0^{\frac12}\int_{-\sqrt{1-4z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-4z^2}}\int_{2z}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y,z)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dz\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply, joriki, but could you explain how did you get $\left | x \right | < \sqrt{1-y^2}$. Is there something to do with the fact that $-1< x < 1$ = $\left | x \right | < 1$

Comment: @user2875613: No -- as I indicated, I solved the second inequality for $x$.

Comment: I see, cause I solved the second inequality without the modulus, instead the in-equality I got was $y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$, since y $\geq$ 0 and $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is also $\geq$ 0, hence I square both sides and solve the inequalities from there, the rest is same as yours

Comment: Finally (sorry for the repeated comments), why is the innermost integral $\int _{2z} ^ \sqrt{1-x^2}$, at first I would have written it as $\int _{0} ^ \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Was wondering if you could correct my misconception here. Thanks again

Comment: @user2875613: Those are both quite natural mistakes; in fact I made that second one myself at first while writing the answer :-) The modulus in $|x|\lt\sqrt{1-y^2}$ arises because you can't simply take square roots on both sides of $x^2\lt1-y^2$. This inequality restricts $x$ in both directions, whereas $x\lt\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is only an upper bound and allows for arbitrarily large negative $x$. The modulus form is just shorthand for the two inequalities $x\lt\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and $x\gt-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ that follow from $x^2\lt1-y^2$.

Comment: @user2875613: As for the second mistake, you need to take into account all inequalities in which $y$ is related to variables further out. Since this is now the innermost integral, all variables are further out, so you need to take into account both inequalities with $y$, both $z\lt\frac y2$ and $y\lt\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: @user2875613: Since you already drew a "picture" of the integration region, you should be able to check that $y$ indeed starts at $2z$ and not at $0$.

Comment: That clarifies alot, thank you so much. abeit, I didnt take square root though, I used the difference of square method ($a^2 - b^2 )= (a + b)(a-b)$to solve the the inequality, but all in all, thank you for your explanation, now I have a new technique to play with if I'm stuck in future.